# Convert Sprite into it's Shadow

Tags: iphone, sprite, cocos2d-x, shadow

I want to convert a Sprite into its shadow, I've tried to use `glBlendEquation()` function but it's not giving what I exactly want.I've followed following links for it :

> http://gamedevelopment.games1234.net/view/63538897166780581719204/rendering-shadow-sprites-in-cocos2d-x
>
> http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/shadow-sprites/1214

What's proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

My way to do that - js implementation:

```
shadow = cc.Sprite.create("sameNameAsParentSprite.png");
shadow.setColor(cc.c3b(0, 0, 0));
shadow.setOpacity(50);
parent.addChild(shadow, -1);
shadow.setPosition(cc.p(parent.getContentSize().width * 0.5 + 2, parent.getContentSize().height * 0.5 - 2));
```

Hope it will help you.